# Is there any difference in file size on 32bit and 64 bit platforms, OS could be any

Tags: file, filesystems, operating-system

I would like to display file size on one of my application. Our application most of the unix and windows platforms that to be 32bit and 64bit.
Is there any difference in file size on 32bit and 64 bit platforms, OS could be any.

Comment: Why would there be a difference? 1000 bits = 1000 bits = 1000 bits, in much the same way as 20 inches = 20 inches = 20 inches...

Comment: Is it because of file systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is binary, there should not be any issue of size/FS/VM/OS. If file is text then there could be some delta variations in the file as "\n/"\r" differences between unix and windows.

Answer (score 0):

file size limits could differ based upon 32bit or 64bit data structures used by underlying filesystem

Comment: The application I am working on has support on Windows 32 bit and 64bit. We also support various flavors of UNIX platforms that to be 32bit and 64bit I would like to calculate file size on all the platform...